# Windows 8 on Sony Tap all-in-one

Tags: windows-8

I have a new Sony Tap All-in-one (Intel Core i7, 8gb RAM, 1tb HD) with Windows 8 installed.  I've only had it for a few weeks and I've notice on a couple of occasions that it seems to boot or wake-up from sleep mode to a black screen where all I can see is the mouse cursor.  Had to refresh the PC the first time because of other Windows 8 problems.  The second time it happened I booted to the BIOS setup/config, exited and rebooted.  It came up fine.  It's scary to think that it may happen when I need the PC most.  Anyone else experience this issue and have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

MicStew

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem to me.